# I've read War and Peace for two months

Tags: grammar

> I've read War and Peace for two months.

> I've learned how to ride a bike for two weeks.

These sentences don't work, because of the verbs. The present perfect tense of these verbs means completion, so it doesn't go with a period of time. Present perfect continuous of these verbs, however, does work.

I'm looking for this type of verbs. Because it's very hard for me to find them, I'd like to ask for your help. Would you help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: I see you've had several questions on this topic recently. Something I'd suggest keeping in mind is that it's not really about a particular or special kind of verb. When we talk about duration and you add phrases like "for two weeks" or "for several months" English prefers the continuous, even for words that could technically work in the perfect, like your exercise example from an earlier question.

Comment: Do you suggest the two sentences in my question are correct?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm suggesting.

Comment: After taking a speed-reading course, I read _War and Peace_ in ten minutes. It's about Russia, I think.